# How two reshape two columns into multiple columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiple-columns, reshape

Does anyone know how I can reshape these two columns:

```
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
   379   346
   352   363
   330   371
   309   379
   291   391
   271   402
   268   403
     1     1
     1     1
   406   318
   379   334
   351   351
   329   359
   307   367
   287   378
   267   390
   264   391
```

into these four columns:

```
     1     1    1      1
     1     1    1      1
     1     1    406  318  
   379   346    379  304 
   352   363    351  351 
   330   371    329  359 
   309   379    307  367
   291   391    287  378
   271   402    267  390
   268   403    264  391
```

That is, how to reshape a matrix that is the size of `Nx2` into a size `10xM` in matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution using mat2cell, splitting every 10 rows. Probably easier to understand, because no 3d-matrices are used:

```
cell2mat(mat2cell(x,repmat(10,size(x,1)/10,1),size(x,2))')
```

Second solution using reshape and permute, should be faster but I did not try it.:

```
reshape(permute(reshape(x,10,[],size(x,2)),[1,3,2]),10,[])
```